# I send an invoice but the site does not save. Did I send it wrong? (data=jp)

Tags: python, request

```
import requests
import settings

bilgi = {
    "cmd": "EARSIV_PORTAL_FATURA_OLUSTUR",
    "pageName": ""
}
jp = {
    "belgeNumarasi"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "faturaTarihi"  :  "21/01/2022",
    "saat"  :  "12:50:00",
    "paraBirimi"  :  "TRY",
    "dovzTLkur"  :  "0",
    "faturaTipi"  :  "SATIS",
    "hangiTip"  :  "5000/30000",
    "vknTckn"  :  "11111111111",
    "aliciUnvan"  :  "Egemen",
    "aliciAdi"  :  "Egemen",
    "aliciSoyadi"  :  "Egemen",
    "binaAdi"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "binaNo"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "kapiNo"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "kasabaKoy"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "vergiDairesi"  :  "MALTEPE",
    "ulke"  :  "Türkiye",
    "bulvarcaddesokak"  :  "DENEME SK. DENEME MAH.",
    "mahalleSemtIlce"  :  " ", # Zorunlu değil
    "sehir"  :  "gheash",
    "postaKodu"  :  "nfdx", # Zorunlu değil
    "tel"  :  "nfdx", # Zorunlu değil
    "fax"  :  "nxc", # Zorunlu değil
    "eposta"  :  "dfs", # Zorunlu değil
    "websitesi"  :  "bsd", # Zorunlu değil
    "iadeTable"  : [], # Zorunlu değil
    "ozelMatrahTutari":  "0", # Zorunlu değil
    "ozelMatrahOrani":  0, # Zorunlu değil
    "ozelMatrahVergiTutari"  :  "0", # Zorunlu değil
    "vergiCesidi"  :  " ", # Zorunlu değil
    "malHizmetTable"  : [],
    "tip"  :  "İskonto",
    "matrah"  :  100,
    "malhizmetToplamTutari"  :  100,
    "toplamIskonto"  :  "0",
    "hesaplanankdv"  :  18,
    "vergilerToplami"  :  18,
    "vergilerDahilToplamTutar"  :  118,
    "odenecekTutar"  :  118,
    "not"  :  "xxx", # Zorunlu değil
    "siparisNumarasi"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "siparisTarihi"  :  "21/01/2022", # Zorunlu değil
    "irsaliyeNumarasi"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "irsaliyeTarihi"  :  "21/01/2022", # Zorunlu değil
    "fisNo"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "fisTarihi"  :  "21/01/2022", # Zorunlu değil
    "fisSaati"  :  "12:30", # Zorunlu değil
    "fisTipi"  :  " ", # Zorunlu değil
    "zRaporNo"  :  "", # Zorunlu değil
    "okcSeriNo"  :  "" # Zorunlu değil
}

jp["malHizmetTable"] = [{
    "malHizmet":  "Yazılım Geliştirme",
    "miktar":  28,
    "birim":  "DAY",
    "birimFiyat":  "3",
    "fiyat":  "84",
    "iskontoOrani":  0,
    "iskontoTutari":  "0",
    "iskontoNedeni":  "",
    "malHizmetTutari":  "99",
    "kdvOrani":  18,
    "vergiOrani": 0,
    "kdvTutari":  "15.12",
    "vergininKdvTutari":  "0",
    "ozelMatrahTutari": ""
},
    {"malHizmet":  "Yazılım Geliştirme",
    "miktar":  28,
    "birim":  "DAY",
    "birimFiyat":  "3",
    "fiyat":  "84",
    "iskontoOrani":  0,
    "iskontoTutari":  "0",
    "iskontoNedeni":  "",
    "malHizmetTutari":  "99",
    "kdvOrani":  18,
    "vergiOrani": 0,
    "kdvTutari":  "15.12",
    "vergininKdvTutari":  "0",
    "ozelMatrahTutari": ""}
]


with requests.Session() as ses:
    #url = "https:#earsivportal.efatura.gov.tr/intragiris.html" #
    url = "https://earsivportaltest.efatura.gov.tr/login.jsp"
    #r = ses.get(url, headers=headers) #
    r = ses.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)

    url1 = "https://earsivportaltest.efatura.gov.tr/earsiv-services/assos-login"

    giris_yap = ses.post(url1, data=settings.user_data)

    response = giris_yap.content
    response = str(response)
    response = response.split(":")
    response = response[1].split('"')
    token = str(response[1])
    print(token)

    url1 ="https://earsivportaltest.efatura.gov.tr/index.jsp?token="
    url1 = url1+token
    print(url1)
    bill = ses.post(url1, headers=bilgi, data=jp)
    print(bill.content)
    print(bill.status_code)
```

settigs :
user_data = {
"assoscmd": "login",
"rtype": "json",
"userid": "33333304",
"sifre": "1",
"parola": "1",
}

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
"Host": "earsivportal.efatura.gov.tr",
"Origin": "https://earsivportal.efatura.gov.tr",
"Referer": "https://earsivportal.efatura.gov.tr/intragiris.html",
"sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
"sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"assoscmd": "anologin",
"cmd": "login"

}

I send an invoice but the site does not save. Did I send it wrong? (data=jp)
When I enter the site, I can't see my invoice in the invoices section.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: If the request was successful then `bill.status_code` would be 201 or 200. If you sent it wrong then the response code would start with a 4 and there is likely an error message in `bill.content`.

Comment: code 200 is coming but it is not run